# Offline синтез речи

Tags: python, golang, tts

Знаю есть TTS от Yandex`a, Google`а, Amazon`а, но всё это в облаке и некоторые даже платные. Есть ещё говорилка и TP, но не нашёл API для работы с ними.

В идеале хотелось бы либу Go/Python для работы с голосовыми движками.

Comment: пробовали какие-нибудь решения, которые гугл по "offline tts" ключевым словам показывает такие как pyttsx, mary.dfki.de, hts, [mimic](https://mycroft.ai/documentation/mimic/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл хороший синтезатор речи под Linux `RHVoice`. Установка:

```
sudo apt-get install scons gcc flite flite1-dev expat libunistring-dev     
libsox-dev
sudo apt-get install libasound-dev
sudo apt-get install libpulse-dev libao-dev 

sudo git clone https://github.com/Olga-Yakovleva/RHVoice
cd RHVoice
sudo scons
sudo scons install
sudo ldconfig
```

Использование

```
echo «Текст» | RHVoice-test -p anna
```

Хороший русский голос - anna.
Английский - alan.

[Источник](https://pythono.ru/linux-rhvoice/)